# What is the limit of the following function?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left ( n-1-2\left (\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma((n-1)/2)} \right )^2 \right )$

Comment: You can try for even and odd values of $n$ separately and use the result $\Gamma(1/2)=\pi^{1/2}$. It should not be too difficult to perform the calculations. Let me know if you are able to work it out in this manner.

Comment: Thanks Paramanand

Comment: Hint: the limit can be computed from the well-known $$\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to proceed using the following approximation for $\Gamma $ function $$\log \Gamma(x) =x\log x-x+\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{2\pi}{x}+\frac{1}{12(x+1)}+o(1/x)$$ and therefore we have $$2\log\frac{\Gamma(x/2)}{\Gamma ((x-1)/2)}=\log\frac{x-1}{2}+(x-1)\log\frac{x}{x-1}-1-\frac{1}{3(x+1)(x+2)}+o(1/x)$$ or $$2\log\frac{\Gamma (x/2)}{\Gamma ((x-1)/2)}=\log\frac{x-1}{2}-\frac{1}{2(x-1)}+o(1/x)$$ Exponentiating we get $$2\left(\frac{\Gamma (x/2)}{\Gamma ((x-1)/2)}\right)^{2}=(x-1)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(x-1)}+o(1/x)\right)$$ or $$2\left(\frac{\Gamma (x/2)}{\Gamma ((x-1)/2)}\right)^{2}=(x-1)-\frac{1}{2}+o(1)$$ It now follows that the desired limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left((x-1)-2\left(\frac{\Gamma (x/2)}{\Gamma ((x-1)/2)}\right)^{2}\right)$$ is $1/2$. Note that it is important to deal with error terms properly to get a rigorous evaluation of the limit in question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
{{\Gamma (n/2)} \over {\Gamma (n/2 - 1/2)}} = \left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,1/2\,} } 
$$
where $x^{\,\overline {\,a\,}} $ denotes the *Rising Factorial* (rising Pochammer).

It is an increasing function for $1<n$.
Because of that and considering the rules for summing the exponents of the Rising Factorial, we have:
$$
\left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right) = \left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,1\,} }  = \left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\,1/2\,\,} } \left( {n/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\,1/2\,\,} }  > \left( {\left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\,1/2\,\,} } } \right)^{\,2} 
$$
and
$$
\left( {n/2 - 1} \right) = \left( {n/2 - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,1\,} }  = \left( {n/2 - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\,1/2\,\,} } \left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\,1/2\,\,} }  < \left( {\left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\,1/2\,\,} } } \right)^{\,2} 
$$
which means
$$
\left( {n/2 - 1} \right) < \left( {\left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\,1/2\,\,} } } \right)^{\,2}  < \left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)
$$
and therefore we know that the given function is bound between $0$ and $1$
$$
0 < n - 1 - 2\left( {\left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\,1/2\,\,} } } \right)^{\,2}  < 1\quad \left| {\;1 < n} \right.
$$

The Stirling series for the rising factorial is
$$
z^{\,\overline {\,w\,} }  \propto z^{\,w} \left( {1 + {{w\left( {w - 1} \right)} \over {2\,z}} + O\left( {{1 \over {z^{\,2} }}} \right)} \right)\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;\left| z \right| \to \infty  \hfill \cr 
  \;\left| {\arg (z + w)} \right| < \pi  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
so we get
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,1/2\,} }  \propto \left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,1/2\,} \left( {1 + {{\,1/2\,\left( {\,1/2\, - 1} \right)} \over {2\,\left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)}} + O\left( {{1 \over {n^{\,2} }}} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{{n - 1} \over 2}} \right)^{\,1/2\,} \left( {1 - {{\,1} \over {4\,\left( {n - 1} \right)}} + O\left( {{1 \over {n^{\,2} }}} \right)} \right) \cr} 
$$
and finally
$$
\eqalign{
  & n + 1 - 2\left( {\left( {n/2 - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,1/2\,} } } \right)^{\,2}  \propto n + 1 - \left( {n - 1} \right)\left( {1 - {{\,1} \over {2\,\left( {n - 1} \right)}} + O\left( {{1 \over {n^{\,2} }}} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2} + O\left( {{1 \over n}} \right) \cr} 
$$

Answer (score -1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left (n-1-2\left (\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma((n-1)/2)} \right )^2 \right)
& = \lim _{n\rightarrow \:\infty \:}\:\left(n-1-2\left(\frac{\frac{2\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!}{n}}{\frac{2\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)!}{n-1}}\right)^2\right)
\\& = \lim _{n\rightarrow \:\infty \:}\:\left(n-1-2\left(\frac{\frac{2\left(\sqrt{2\pi \:\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{e}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\right)}{n}}{\frac{2\left(\sqrt{2\pi \:\:\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}{e}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)}{n-1}}\right)^2\right)
\\& = \lim _{n\rightarrow \:\infty \:}\:\left(n-1-\frac{n^{n-1}\left(n-1\right)^{-n+2}}{e}\right)
\\& = \lim _{t\rightarrow 0\:}\:\left(\frac{1}{t}-1-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-1}\left(\frac{1}{t}-1\right)^{-\frac{1}{t}+2}}{e}\right)
\\& = \lim _{t\rightarrow 0\:}\:\left(\frac{e-\left(-t+1\right)^{\frac{2t-1}{t}}}{et}-1\right)
\\& = \lim _{t\rightarrow 0\:}\:\left(\frac{e-\left(e-\frac{3et}{2}+o\left(t\right)\right)}{et}-1\right)
\\& = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Solved with Stirling's approximation and Taylor expansion

Comment: How do you justify the use of Stirling formula here? There is no rule in theory of limits which allows such replacements.

Comment: You need to make a careful analysis of the error terms involved in Stirling's formula. The way you have used Stirling's formula in your second step can not be justified without it. And the answer as it stands is wrong.